# How to document an Ember App?

Tags: ember.js, yuidoc

I'm using YUIdoc. Anything else ? Well could anyone tell me how to properly document a model, a controller, a mixin and a view in Ember ?

For example I'm trying to document this:

```
App.newModel = DS.Model.extend({
    someProperty: DS.attr('string')
});

App.myController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    someProperty: ...
});

App.myMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    someProperty: ...
});
```

**EDIT** I'm now using YUIdoc instead of jsdoc3

Comment: I've been struggling with how to document computed properties and observers as well. I'll report back if I find any solid exampled.

Answer (score 10):

You're going to have a hard time using JSDoc for Ember applications because JSDoc parses code and not just comments. Ember uses their own class-like syntax, so JSDoc isn't going to be able to recognize a lot of the code. I personally use [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/), which is what the Ember team uses. (YUIDoc also allows you to import other documentation to resolve external references, like `DS.Model`.) There are other alternatives though. [This page](http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2013/12/jsdoc-vs-yuidoc-vs-doxx-vs-docco-choosing-a-javascript-documentation-generator/) does some comparison, and gives you a difference chart that shows you which tools parse comments rather than source code.

Also, I realize that I am not answering your specific question. But this should help answer the question of what alternatives are out there, which may eliminate your JSDoc question altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I also did more research and now I'm using YUIdoc. Can you make an answer for this documentor ?

Answer (score 3):

I have found [ember-style-guide](https://github.com/softlayer/ember-style-guide#comments) useful to me. But with few changes:

1. After the `@module` statement I write full path to it beginning from the project name. It gives me opportunity to link to it. For example:

   ```
   /**
    * @module dashboard/models/node
    * @augments module:ember-data/system/model
    * @public
    */
   export default DS.Model.extend({

     /**
      * @type {module:dashboard/models/node}
      */
     parent: DS.belongsTo("node"),

     /**
      * @type {Array<module:dashboard/models/node>}
      */
     childs: DS.hasMany("node"),

     /**
      * @method
      * @return {module:dashboard/models/node}
      */
     getFirstChild() {
       // ...
     }

   });
   ```
2. After the `@augments` statement I write a full path to module from which the current module is extended. If the module extended from a third part module I write full path of that module (getting it from the `import` statement). I'm not sure that it's right way, because in the generated doc no links to these modules. I did not found a way to make a link to them. Honestly, I'm not sure that is possible because different projects may use different doc comments engines and there is no way to tie modules (classes) by names.